# Apply different AttributeTransformers for tables involved in DynamoDB transaction

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

Is there any way to use different AttributeTransformers for various tables involved in a ddb transaction. I looked at DynamoDBMapper [code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.java#L1114), it looks like the same transformers are applied to all the operations. Is there any ready-made solution to use different transformers? One option I see is to enhance the transformers to process records of the intended tables only, any simpler solution?